# hadoop jar ignores specified main class

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

My hadoop version is 0.20.2.
Although I type

```
hadoop jar JarWithSeveralMainClasses.jar NonDefaultMainClass args...
```

It tries to execute `main` method of `MainClassSpecifiedInJarManifest`.
Why?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may find your answer [here](http://www.roman10.net/specify-the-main-class-in-a-jar-file-for-hadoop/)

> If a jar file contains a main class specified in its manifest file, **hadoop will take the main class even if the command specify another main class**. This is different from normal java execution where we can specify a main class to overwrite the one in the manifest file.
>
> If a jar file **does not contain a main class in manifest file**, hadoop allows us to specify the main class.